# valgrind gives a wrong size of uninitialised

Tags: c, valgrind

The sample2.c code I see from a blog to illustrate uninitialised value using valgrind. Here is the code:
sample2.c:

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2  
 3  int main()
 4  {
 5      int a[5];
 6      int i,s;
 7      a[0]=a[1]=a[3]=a[4]=0;
 8      
 9      printf("%d\n",a[2]);
10      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
11      s += a[i];
12      
13      if(s == 377)
14      printf("sum is %d\n",s);
15      return 0;
16  }
```

using gcc -g -o sample2 sample2.c

valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes  ./sample2

I got the valgrind check information below.

I don't understand why Use of uninitialised value of size 8 due to sizeof(int) == 4 in my machine? I ran the program in x64 machine,so Is this will be pointer?

```
==31419== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==31419==    at 0x4E7F1CB: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==31419==    by 0x4E83450: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
```

Full check message below:

```
 ==31419== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==31419== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==31419== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==31419== Command: ./sample2
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==31419==    at 0x4E81AFE: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
    ==31419==    at 0x4E7F1CB: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E83450: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==31419==    at 0x4E7F1D5: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E83450: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==31419==    at 0x4E8349F: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==31419==    at 0x4E81BCB: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==31419==    at 0x4E81C4E: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x4E8A338: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
    ==31419==    by 0x400561: main (sample2.c:9)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    4195392
    ==31419== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==31419==    at 0x400588: main (sample2.c:13)
    ==31419==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==31419==    at 0x40052D: main (sample2.c:4)
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==31419==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==31419==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
    ==31419== 
    ==31419== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a 64-bit processor. Even though the value itself is 32 bits, it is passed into `printf` in a 64-bit *register*; this comes from the System-V calling convention for x86-64.

However it doesn't seem to trigger an error until later at which point valgrind seems to only know that the value is sign-extended to 64 bits and originally came from your `main` function (even the line number is wrong there.

---

If you compile this with `-m32` and somehow manage to run it under valgrind (I needed to install additional 32-bit packages on Ubuntu), you can indeed see 4 here:

```
==4854== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==4854==    at 0x48A3CAB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==4854==    by 0x48A85C5: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==4854==    by 0x48AF2F5: printf (printf.c:33)
==4854==    by 0x1085D0: main (sample2.c:9)
==4854== 
==4854== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4854==    at 0x48A3CB3: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==4854==    by 0x48A85C5: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==4854==    by 0x48AF2F5: printf (printf.c:33)
==4854==    by 0x1085D0: main (sample2.c:9)
==4854==
```

---

One thing to note here is that the value in the `int` `a[2]` is indeterminate, but there are no trap values of type `int` and it has its address taken of, so passing it into a function does not have undefined behaviour - but its use in a library function does.